# Enable a button when the user has reached the end of the modal in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Hello i have a modal with terms and conditions and i want to make the button that the user agrees enable when has reached the end of the modal. I am using react class components and the modal is a component from antd.

```
   render() {
    return(
        <Modal 
            title={
                <h1>
                    <b>Terms and Conditions</b>
                </h1>
            }
            open={this.state.visible}
            width={800}
            bodyStyle={{ height: '400px', overflowY: 'auto'}}
            closable={false}
            footer={                    
                <Button 
                    type="primary"
                    disabled={this.state.agreeTerm} 
                >
                    Accept
                </Button>
            }
        >
        <div>......</div>
        </Modal>
```

As you can see the button in on the footer of the modal. I was thinking using refs but modal on antd design has not ref attribute.
On `componentDidMount` i was thinking add this `this.modalRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)` an the `handleScroll` function be like this

```
handleScroll = () => {
    console.log('ref is  :', this.modalRef.current)
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = this.modalRef.current
    this.setState({
      agreeTerm: scrollTop + clientHeight < scrollHeight
    })
}
```

But this not working. Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a div at the bottom of the modal. Use IntersectionObserver to track if the user has reached the bottom. Then update the state

A boolean state is enough for your use case, not need to update it on each scroll

Answer (score 0):

So it might seem a little bit daunting with you.
You can check out this hook https://usehooks.com/useOnScreen/

It seems you using Class Component, just using componentDidMount instead of useEffect
and componentWillUnmount to unobserve as same as return of useEffect.

**Ref is attribute of Button at footer.**

```
observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([entry]) => {
   // Update our state when observer callback fires
   this.setState({intersecting: entry.isIntersecting});
  },
  { rootMargin }
);
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.ref.current) {
      this.observer.observe(this.ref.current);
  }
}
```

```
componentWillUnmount() {
 this.observer.unobserve(this.ref.current);
}
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Hello i have follow your advice but i have a problem with my code again. The problem is that the observer in not consolelog nothing in `componentDidMount` 
`
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        ([entry]) => {
          console.log('Inside')
          this.setState({ agreeTerm: entry[0].isIntersecting });
          console.log('Help :', entry[0].isIntersecting)
        },
        {
          root: null,
          threshold: 1,
          rootMargin: "0px",
        }
      )
`
I am using ref in a div element in the end of the modal @tanthuann

Comment: I solve my problem using component did update

Comment: @The_elevator I think you should create the instance (this.observer) in constructor. And it worked?

Comment: I create the `observer` in `componentDidMount` and i call it in `componentDidUpdate` using `ref`